# asp .net serve 2 web

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using Owin File System to host static files.
I got some information from the following:

[Using a wwwroot folder (ASP.NET 5 style) in ASP.NET 4.5 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36294188/using-a-wwwroot-folder-asp-net-5-style-in-asp-net-4-5-project)

I am good with hosting static files from wwwroot. There is a index.html which the URL fetches back.

However what I need is another website called wwwroot2 to be hosted under same application. 
How do I achieve that? I tried duplicating the about code for new file system. That doesn't work.

Comment: You need another *website* to run under `wwwroot2`? That doesn't make any sense. The wwwroot folder is for serving static files in an application, not for hosting websites in an application

Comment: let me explain little more.When I try to load the site using 'http://localhost', index.html is retrieved. This works as expected.
Now, I want to fetch index2.html under wwwroot, using 'http://localhost/index2.html'. This doesn't work. I see, it still retrieves index.html(not sure why this is happening). Now index2.html has its own css,js files which itself can be a single page website.

Comment: Which service are you using? ISS,Apache , etc.

Comment: its a ASP .NET server... turns out I am hitting https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2398. the static pages (index.html) are npm build output of a react app. there is a service-worker.js that always loads irrespective of the path you specify. It goofs up the URIs.

Comment: Heres whats happening. service-worker.js is cached in the browser once index.html is loaded. This stays in the cache even when I closed the browser. For all the new pages(index2.html), the site tries to load all references of this service-worker.js (which was cached when index.html loaded) which could lead to something unintentional. In my case, this service-worker.js was trying to load lot many files and other static files apart from index2.html. I deleted the service-worker.js from the server, service-worker.js on the browser and it started working as expected.