# WWWROOT in MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-5, url-rewriting, static-files

How to achieve same behavior in ASP.NET MVC5 with static files like it works on aspnet-core with `app.UseDefaultFiles(); app.UseStaticFiles();`?

I mean serving static files from some folder over root, e.g. `/wwwroot/some.html` must be opened on `mysite.com/some.html`, `/wwwroot/img/test.jpg` on `mysite.com/img/test.jpg` etc.

**Update**: I have created `wwwroot` folder and added following rule to `web.config`:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Rewrite Static" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(?!(wwwroot/|api/))(.*)$" ignoreCase="true"></match>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/wwwroot/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
```

So IIS must return files from `wwwroot` except when calls go to `/api/something`, but I'm always getting `index.html` in `wwwroot` folder and never other files. Api's URL works good.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Look at this and see if it is of any help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-custom-routes-cs

Comment: Updated with rewrite.

Comment: Have you considered using owin middleware to serve static files? https://stackoverflow.com/q/36294188/350384

Answer (score 1):

All works in that way:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Rewrite Static" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^((?!(wwwroot\/|api\/))(.*))$" ignoreCase="true"></match>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/wwwroot/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="StaticFile"/>
      <add
                name="StaticFile"
                path="*" verb="*"
                modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule"
                resourceType="Either"
                requireAccess="Read" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
    </handlers>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".*" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
    </staticContent>
    <modules>
      <remove name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" />
      <add name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" type="Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation.TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule, Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation" preCondition="integratedMode,managedHandler" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```

Don't forget to [install rewrite module](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite).